# jetty-maven-plugin 9.4.x doesn't seem to obey the jetty:run command

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I've tried rolling an existing project forward from `9.3.x` and then running the: `mvn jetty:run` command.

But it just goes through the build and ends on "build success" without actually spinning up/starting the server.

Has anyone else come across this problem/can reproduce?

(Tried with maven 3.3 and 3.5)

Comment: Please share the build log to see what happens. Your `pom.xml` might also help

Comment: What do you expect `jetty:run` to do?  And be specific, which exact versions  of Jetty and Maven were you using?  Some examples of the pom.xml would be nice.  The logging output too.  (also, as this is common, make sure your project's `<packaging>war</packaging>` is defined as war).

Comment: I'll post more details in a bit. but cc-ing from my original post: using Jetty 9.4.x, Maven 3.3 & 3.5. Expected result is that it runs/launches a jetty server that hosts the web app. (just like it has done when it is 9.3.x.)

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and @JoakimErdfelt hit the nail on the head; my POM didn't specify WAR packaging, and once I added that everything immediately worked as expected. Thanks, @JoakimErdfelt!

Comment: For me (jar packaged module) it helped to add the following parameter to jetty-maven-plugin configuration:
`<supportedPackagings>jar</supportedPackagings>`